# GCC: trying to use -Werror or -pedantic using pragmas

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

In files being compiled using gcc (several .c and .cpp files) I have currently something like:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
    #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wall"
#endif
```

The purpose of specifying inline options instead of just using the command line is to control after which points I'm interesting in going more strict (e.g., after the `#include` list).

It works fine. I then tried to add `-Wextra` with:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
    #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wall -Wextra"
#endif
```

It fails. Apparently, you can't use more than one option in a single `pragma`, and you have to use several lines instead:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
    #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wall"
    #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wextra"
#endif
```

- **Q1:** Is there a way to specify several options inline?

Next, I tried to add `-Werror` and `-pedantic`, and neither using `diagnostic warning` nor `diagnostic error` works. Example:

```
    #pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Werror"
```

fails with: `warning: ‘-Werror’ is not an option that controls warnings`. How can I solve this? which other alternatives there's besides `diagnostic [warning|error]`? What about `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors`? Because I'm aware pedantic is mostly related with standard compliance rather than diagnostic control and I don't know if I can even specify it inline.

Comment: Why is having multiple `#pragma` lines a problem?

Comment: Generally speaking, exercise control over compiler diagnostics at build time, via your compiler command line, makefile, or other build tool.  Encoding diagnostic-control information into your source files has bad code smell.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There's various fun stuff you can do which ought to be in the specific file though, like `#pragma message "TODO fix all the bugs here"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't. It's just how it is.

You can turn specific warnings on or off, or turn them into errors, but you can't do everything with `#pragma` as you have noticed. Note that `"-Wpedantic"` can still be controlled.

In general, I still put most options into the build file, including `-Werror`. I don't think it's such a great idea to keep switching around warnings for sections of code.

In the (rare-ish) case that some header gives warnings, I use pragmas to disable them for that header -- `push` the settings, disable warning, include header, `pop` the settings. This leads to constructs like

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-conversion"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow"
#endif

#include "External/ProtoPuf/message.h"

#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif
```

However, I don't use stuff like this for my own code -- instead, I fix the warnings in the code, or remove the warning from the build system if it's too annoying.

Comment: Yes.  I'm inclined to say that GCC's diagnostic-control pragmas are best suited for *disabling* specific diagnostics for code that otherwise would elicit them, but which you are confident you want to accept as-is.  Even that I would consider a bit questionable, but I could see my way to doing it under some circumstances.  Generally speaking, the person building the code should be allowed to exercise their discretion about what diagnostics they want to see.  Including when that is a different person from the one who wrote the code.

Comment: It's not questionable for me. I don't mess with 3rd party libraries unless I absolutely have to -- and I build with `-Werror`. So, one way or another, I have to get rid of the warnings, preferably without touching the foreign code. But even without `-Werror`, having warnings appear that have been "checked and deemed ok" still clobbers other warnings, so it's always best to just get rid of all warnings. `-Werror` simply forces that to "now", as opposed to "yeah, I'll do it next week".

Comment: As I said, "I could see my way to doing it under some circumstances." Most of the time, though, I am already dissatisfied with third-party headers that produce compilation warnings, and hiding them, pragmatic as that may be, does not make me any more satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to specify several options inline?

If you for some reason has to write out the pragma on a single line, because you are making a function-like macro or similar, you can use the `_Pragma` operator which is similar to `#pragma` but can be used a bit more flexibly. It works exactly the same, just squeeze what you would type after `#pragma` in a string literal. And if what you typed happened to be a string literal, then add escape sequences `\"`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHECK_ALL_THE_STUFF                      \
  _Pragma ("GCC diagnostic push")                \
  _Pragma ("GCC diagnostic warning \"-Wall\"")   \
  _Pragma ("GCC diagnostic warning \"-Wextra\"") \

#define YOU_ARE_NO_FUN_ANYMORE                   \
  _Pragma ("GCC diagnostic pop")                 \

int main() 
{
  CHECK_ALL_THE_STUFF
    printf("%d\n", 1.0f);
  YOU_ARE_NO_FUN_ANYMORE
  
  printf("%d\n", 1.0f);
}
```

This gives me a warning for the first `printf` line

> warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double'

But not for the second one.

---

> Next, I tried to add -Werror and -pedantic, and neither using diagnostic warning nor diagnostic error works.

Not all compiler options can be used like this, simple as that. Basically only the `-W...` ones work. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

As noted in another answer by @Christian Stieber, `-Wpedantic` is a work-around to enable that particular option.